# Running pssh as a cron job

Tags: ssh, cron

I have the script below.

```
OUTPUT_FOLDER=/home/user/output
LOGFILE=/root/log/test.log
HOST_FILE=/home/user/host_file.txt

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_FOLDER

rm -f $OUTPUT_FOLDER/*

pssh -h $HOST_FILE -o $OUTPUT_FOLDER "cat $LOGFILE | tail -n 100 | grep foo"
```

When I run this script on its own, it works fine and the `$OUTPUT_FOLDER` contains the output from the servers in the `$HOST_FILE`. However, when I ran the script as a cronjob, the `$OUTPUT_FOLDER` is created, but it's always empty. It's as if the `pssh` command was never executed.

Why is this? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Is the output folder created? Or is it already there from the last time you ran the script manually?

Comment: What does the output of the cronjob look like? (It will normally be emailed to the user who created it, but you might need to explicitly check your local mailbox on that computer instead of your regular email account).

Comment: When I tried to run it without the cron job, I always delete the output folder first before running the script, so it does create the output folder. When I run it in as a cron job, the output fodler is created in the first execution, then it remains there subsequently.

Comment: The output of the cron job should be the lines containing the word "foo".

Comment: I'm more concerned with what the output (to STDERR/STDOUT) of the cron job *actually is* (since it might include error messages) than what it should be.

Comment: I have changed the script such that it runs in an infinite loop (no cron job) and sleeps for 15 minutes after each loop. In this case, I also see the same situation where the `$OUTPUT_FOLDER` is empty. So I don't think this is a cron job issue.

Is it possible that I need to wait for a while after clearing the contents of the `$OUTPUT_FOLDER` before launching pssh?